# Button on user profile page to send email

Tags: users, emails

I think this is pretty simple, but I don't know what's the best way to achieve this.

This is what I need:

- Add a button on each user profile page. When another user clicks on the button, it opens a form (in a popup window would be great) to write the message. The email should be sent to the user of the profile page we are seeing.

If it's not possible to add a form, I just need a "mailto:useremail" so when i click the button opens the outlook our gmail, wtv.

How can I do this? Is there a simple way?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, both solutions are great, I managed to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem please :)

Answer (score 2):

To get what you want, you need to modify the template user, to do this you need to follow the next steps:

1. Find the file called **user-profile.tpl** it is in the module user **modules\user** (**NOT** inside **sites/all/modules**).
2. Once you found it, open it, and you should see at the end of the file something like this:

> print render($user_profile);

3. Now copy and paste this line of code inside php tags:

> $usr = user_load(arg(1));
>
> echo 'mail.'?Subject=textyouwant"
>   target="_blank">Send Mail';

That should work !

Answer (score 2):

@Drii7, Drupal provides with a default [contact us](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contact) form, but if you insist to use the `mailto:username`, you can overwrite the template in the `user` module as suggested by @DarkteK. 
You can copy the file in your `theme's` templates folder and add a `mailto` link where you want.